# When will web proxy be supported by OpenTok SDK for Windows

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Some OpenTok Developer documentation indicates the Windows SDK v2.16 will support OpenTok communication via web proxy, and that this is currently in Beta.  Has anyone on the Beta program seen this work, and is there any indication of when the 2.16 SDK for Windows may be released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael here from the OpenTok team.

We are planning on releasing this feature (IP Proxy) to GA later this month. And we just released SDK 2.17.